# Regular expression to match key-value pairs

Tags: regex

**I need to get result**:
Weight: About 17 lbs
Color: Black
Load capacity: 263 lbs
Tested for: 120-150 kg (263-330 lbs) dynamic state
etc
 **from string:**
Weight: About 17 lbs Color: Black Load capacity: 263 lbs Tested for: 120-150 kg (263-330 lbs) dynamic state Overall dimension: 22.5" x 21.5" x 35"- 39" (L x W x H) Backrest size:17.5" x 19" Seat size:17.5" x 17.5" Adjustable chair seat: 18"-22"
I got just keys, regex:
`[A-Z][a-z]*(\s[a-z]*)*[:]`
[regex result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpFkX.png)

Comment: How would you know where one pair stops and another starts?

Comment: [capitalized word][:][something before another capitalized word:]

Comment: More information would be helpful, are those properties always in the same order? Have you tried already? please share what you have done so far so people may get a better idea of the problem.

Comment: "About" is a capitalised word, as is "Black". Let's say we allow the first character of the value to be a capital, what about "Overall dimension: 22.5" x 21.5" x 35"- 39" (L x W x H)"? The **L** should now start a new key, so you actually get first key-value pair `Overall dimension` + `22.5" x 21.5" x 35"- 39" (` next one `L x W x H) Backrest size` + `17.5" x 19"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have captured and grouped key values.

```
([A-Z][a-z]+(?:\s+[a-z]+)*)[:]\s*(\S+.*?(?=[A-Z][a-z]+|$))
```

Check this link: https://regex101.com/r/e1E06V/1/